# Joomla 3.8 - can't approve user registrations

Tags: joomla, user-registration

The latest update of Joomla added 'New ACL Verification on approving an user after email notification' See [Joomla 3.8.13 Security Notice](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Joomla_3.8.13_Security_Notes)

I can now no longer approve user registrations, even when logging in as super user.  It does not redirect me to the activation URL but instead I get the following message:

*You are not authorised to view this resource.*

Any help would be much apprchiated.